# Why does after derefrencing the pointer prints different values?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
}

void foo(int **const p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

The above `code` prints :

```
11 11 Undefined-value
```

Why is third time an undefined value printed?
Why doesn't it print `11` at the last?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, you're only guaranteed to get the first 11. The other two print statements could print anything

Comment: i got 11 11 and an undefined value

Comment: **Sometimes** you get 11 11 and an undefined value. Sometimes you won't .

Comment: This link shows that the first call to `printf` in `main` is already problematic in principle, and lets you experiment with the fixes offered in the answers: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/c545ff40

Comment: Is this worthy of inclusion in the wiki if for no other reason than it serves as a very visible demonstration of the dangers of undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of `foo`, you set `*p` (which is the same as `p` in `main`) to the address of a local variable.  When `foo` returns, that variable goes out of scope, so that address doesn't point to anyplace meaningful.

Returning the address of a local variable and subsequently dereferencing that address invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As to what is *probably* happening, when you first read `*p` after returning from `foo`, the address where `j` was residing on the stack hasn't yet been reused since no other function has been called.  When you then call `printf`, that address does get reused inside the stack frame of `printf`.  Then the next time `*p` is read, it contains whatever the last function call put there.

To reiterate however, this is undefined behavior, so you can't depend on this happening.  Compiling with a different compiler or even the same compiler with different optimization settings can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.

As an example of undefined behavior, I get the following output when compiling with gcc with -O0:

```
11 11 11
```

With -O1:

```
11 11 0
```

With -O2:

```
11 0 0
```

With -O3:

```
11 0 0
```

Notice that in one case we get the "expected" output, while in the other cases we don't, and in different ways.

You can avoid this issue by either defining `j` as `static` or at file scope (i.e. outside of a function) in which case the variable's lifetime is the lifetime of the full program and thus its address is always valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (dont define `int j` as local variable) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int **const p);
int j = 11;          // define int j outside of the function as public

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);

    printf("%d ", *p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
}

void foo(int **const p)
{
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

Output will be :

```
11 11 11
```

When you defined  `int j = 11;` in `void foo(int **const p)` these steps heppens :

1. `*p` take `j` address
2. so `**p` will be `11` and `foo` function return

Now because `int j;` is local, So `j` memory will be destroyed after `foo` called!

And `**p` point to an undefined contents, in this state you get `Undefined-value` output.

Comment: @Sanj.K if this help you, please accept this answer.

Comment: **p does not point to an undefined address. It points to an address with undefined contents. And that's not the point anyway. The point is the undefined behavior when you dereference that address .